# Why do I get this bracket not closed error

Tags: python, error-handling, scrapy

I am attempting to learn scrapy but I have run across this error and can't seem to find where it is coming from. The error appears on the final row under the ( after response.xpath

```
import scrapy
import logging

class CountriesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'countries'
    allowed_domains = ['www.worldometers.info']
    start_urls = ['https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/']

    def parse(self, response):
        countries = response.xpath("//td/a")
        for country in countries:
            name = country.xpath(".//text()").get()
            link = country.xpath(".//@href").get()

            # absolute_url = f"htpps://www.worldometers.info{link}"
            # absolute_url = response.urljoin(link)
            # yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_url) 
            yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_country)
                 
    def parse_country(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("(//table[@class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-list"])[1]/tbody/tr")
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R20de.png)

Answer (score 1):

Last line you are nesting quotes (") inside of a string declared with quotes.

Use \" to escape the quote or declare the quote with ' instead of "

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't used escape key for the **double quotes**

I have corrected below:

```
def parse_country(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("(//table[@class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-list\"])[1]/tbody/tr")
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight and prompt response.